# how can I sort an array in php?

Tags: php

Example :

```
$a [] = array ('google','bing','yahoo');
$a [] = array ('America','France','Germany');
$a [] = array ('Africa','Asia','Europe');
```

And I want to sort her in table like that :

Africa.......
America........
google.......

Comment: It's not completely clear to me what is the output you are expecting...

Comment: Did you mean to put indices in the square brackets?

Comment: @robinjam: That's actually valid syntax, it just appends the values at the end of the array.

Comment: @robinjam, $a[] = $mixed_value, means push $mixed_value into the arra $a

Comment: I see. Well, you learn something new every day :D

Answer (score 3):

You can do `sort($a)`.

This first Google result for "sort array php" is this:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

Comment: sort() do not sort multidimensional arrays. Go figure

Answer (score 2):

You can use [array_multisort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php), specially if your inner arrays has same size. I have checcked it, hope it will serve as you need.

Answer (score 1):

1. Why your array is multidimensional?
2. Join your nested arrays into one, sort it, and then you can output that sorted array in a manner you wish

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$resort = "return (1*strnatcmp(\$x['0'], \$y['0']));";
uasort($a, create_function('$x,$y', $resort));
print_r($a);
```